# Change default startup page for windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I created a new Basic Page called PivotPage.xaml in the Windows Phone 8.1 project of the universal app solution. When I go to **App.xaml** under the Shared partition, **I want to change HubPage in the code below to the newly created PivotPage**. But VS refuses to recognize `PivotPage` as a legitimate type. The namespace of both pages and the class definitions are exactly the same.

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}
```

If there is any other way to change the default page please let me know that too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

WP 8.1 Universal Project

> -> Add New Item -> Blank Page 
>   -> Name it MyPivotPage.xaml

---

MyPivotPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="YOUR_NAMESPACE.MyPivotPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:YOUR_NAMESPACE"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <PivotItem Header="item1">
                <Grid/>
            </PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <PivotItem Header="item2">
                <Grid/>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Change "YOUR_NAMESPACE" to your namespace :)

Then in App.xaml.cs

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyPivotPage), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}
#endif
#if WINDOWS_APP
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}       
#endif
```

---

**Clean your solution**
Set your WP 8.1 Universal as your default startup project
Deploy to your device

Comment: Chubosaurus Software: That's what I have been doing exactly. But the `PivotPage` is not being recognized as a type. Compiler complaint: `The type or namespace name 'PivotPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you're doing incorrectly.  Do Build -> Clean Solution.  Right click on the WP8.1 Project -> Set it as Startup Project. Right click on WP8.1 Project -> Build.  Do not do a "Build Solution", just build that particular project then deploy.  It happens because the other project doesn't have a PivotPage as well, so either add one to the other project or use some #define.  I will modify my solution to show you what I'm talking about.

Comment: The #if directive worked perfectly. Didn't have to clean. Thanks.