# Adding a page before the hub page in a Windows Phone 8.1 store app

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm building a Windows Universal Store App, concentrating first on the Windows Phone 8.1 app. I'm basing my app on a hub app. I want to add a splash page to the app startup to replace the static splash screen with a XAML based animation. I am confused by navigation since it all seems to be set up and owned by the hub page.

I have looked at

- Mike Taulty's blog post about [Windows/Phone 8.1–Frame, Page, NavigationHelper, SuspensionManager](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/05/23/windows-phone-8-1-frame-page-navigationhelper-suspensionmanager.aspx);
- [Quickstart: Navigating between pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx);
- [How to extend the splash screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868191(v=win.10).aspx); and
- [Navigation Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761500.aspx)

In fact the last of those explicitly states that "hub pages are the user's entry point to the app".

How do I add pages to my hub app that the user will encounter before the hub, like a splash page or a logon screen?

Answer (score 1):

Typically no sooner had I posted the question than I saw where to find the answer. When NavigationHelper is added to the project along with the hub page it includes comments explaining how to use it:

> To make use of NavigationHelper, follow these two steps or
>   start with a BasicPage or any other Page item template other than BlankPage.
>
> 1) Create an instance of the NavigationHelper somewhere such as in the 
>   constructor for the page and register a callback for the LoadState and 
>   SaveState events.

```
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
}

private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{ 
}

private async void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{ 
}
```

> 2) Register the page to call into the NavigationHelper whenever the page participates 
>       in navigation by overriding the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page.OnNavigatedTo 
>       and Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page.OnNavigatedFrom events.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

That boiler-plate code only required slight changes in my page: take out the `async`, and make navigationHelper an instance variable.

Then to start in another page follow the instructions in [Set start page in Windows Phone 8.1 universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755439/575530) to edit App.xaml.cs thus:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SplashPage), e.Arguments))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
    }
#endif
#if WINDOWS_APP

    if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage), e.Arguments))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
    }
#endif
```

Then in SplashPage.xaml.cs when I need to navigate to the hub page I add

```
if (rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage)))
{
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create hub page");
}
```